# node write after end error when repeatedly stream read and write

Tags: node.js

Was using this [lib](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-lame) to convert .pcm file to .mp3 file. Sometimes the converted mp3 file would be empty somehow, so wrote a retry mechanism to eliminate the issue:

```
const retriesLimit = 5,
      retryInterval = 5000;

function convert(inputPath, outputPath, retries) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    _convert(inputPath, outputPath, resolve, reject, retries);
  });
}

function _convert(inputPath, outputPath, resolve, reject, retries=0) {    
  if (retries <= retriesLimit) {
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(inputPath),
        writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);

    readStream.pipe(encoder);

    encoder.pipe(writeStream);

    readStream.on('end', () => {
      console.log('pcm read stream ended.');
    });

    readStream.on('error', err => reject(err));
    writeStream.on('error', err => reject(err));

    if (retries) {
      console.log(`Retry ${retries} times to convert pcm to mp3`);
    }

    writeStream.on('finish', () => {
      getFileSize(outputPath)
        .then(size => {
          console.log('Converted mp3 size:', size);
          if (size === 0) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              _convert(inputPath, outputPath, resolve, reject, retries + 1);
            }, retryInterval);
          } else {
            console.log('mp3 file created.');
            resolve(true);
          }
        });
    });
  } else {
    reject(`Converted mp3 file is empty. Retries ${retries} times.`);
  }
}
```

It throws error `Error: write after end` when the retries happened and I don't not understand why.

Comment: Have you tried instantiating the `encoder` on every retry?

Comment: No. That's the problem. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate a new `encoder` on each retry